# Is it a problem that the water in my sump pail covers one of the drain openings without tripping the pump float?

Tags: water, drain, sump

We just had a sump pump & trenched drain pipe installed in our basement. Rained all last night. Crock had filled above one of the drain pipe inlets. I manually activated the pump & it emptied normally. It seemed like another inch or two & the float would have kicked it on. Due to having to go under a sewage drain pipe, one of the plastic drain pipes enters the crock pretty low. Maybe 6"-8" from bottom. My question is... Should the pump kick on before the water level covers the drain pipe. I don't like the idea of all that water sitting in the plastic drain pipe.

Comment: Short-cycling the pump (by setting the float to turn on at a very low level, so there isn't much water to pump each time) will kill your pump faster than a higher setting. I'm not sure what you think is so horrible about water sitting in a plastic drain pipe, but if it does, you should probably get the sump pit made deeper. Or not worry about water sitting in the pipes. Your choice.

Comment: As long as your rate of incoming water is reasonable, there's no problem having one of the pipes coming into the sump pit submerged.  Water basically finds a level.  If you have a rate of incoming flow such that water isn't finding its level, you have a bigger problem than the level of the float.